# how to change menu button color when admin got a new task in admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

i have created a Content management system. Admin got a new task to fulfill in admin panel. admin panel has 10+ buttons in main menu. Default color of menu is black and hover effect is light grey

i want that whenever admin got a new task, button color should change to red or something else and hover effect should be same.
how can i do this ?

Comment: Can you show us your code? If you have new task, just add a classname to button and set new styles.

Comment: just learn how to use session than check that weather session is set or not and letter add class by checking it

Answer (score 1):

That's all I can do according to the few information you gave.

**HTML/PHP**

```
<a class="button <?php if($newtask) echo 'newtask' ?>">
    Your button
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.button:hover{
    background: yellow !important;
}
.button.newtask {
    background: red;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/pop2zt7q/

Comment: +1 btw why js fiddle ? :D i mean you can not use php in jsfiddle :D

Comment: Well, for the graphical part of the question :)